# Google Mobile Vision TextRecognizer not working on device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm reading text from Android camera 
emulator, but it does not work on my Android device.

Here, the TextRecognizer returns false, my application does not continue to run

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            cameraView = FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.surface_view);
            textView=FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text_view);


            TextRecognizer textRecognizer=new TextRecognizer.Builder(ApplicationContext).Build();
            if (!textRecognizer.IsOperational)
            {
                Log.Error("Error","Hata var");

            }
            else
            {
                cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(ApplicationContext, textRecognizer)
                    .SetFacing(CameraFacing.Back)
                    .SetRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                    .SetRequestedFps(2.0f)
                    .SetAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .Build();

                cameraView.Holder.AddCallback(this);
                textRecognizer.SetProcessor(this);
            }
        }
```

All the permissions for devices are open still the App is not able to run on two different devices
LG-Android Version 7.0
Samsung-Android Version 4.2.1

Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

You are never creating/setting the OCR processor on your `TextRecognizer` instance. Once you do that, the Google Play services will also be able to download the correct models to the device if they are not already available.

```
textRecognizer.SetProcessor(new OcrDetectorProcessor(_GraphicOverlay));
```

You will need to subclass `Detector.Processor` and implement the `ReceiveDetections` (override) method.

re: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/Detector

Comment: I'm not good enough to know what you say


I followed this example
This example worked correctly
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aRlYjSQPc8